# Changing object properties in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, static-methods

consider the following objects:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0
    def increase(self):
        S.increase(self)

class S(object):
    @staticmethod
    def increase(item):
        item.c += 1
```

This mirrors the situation I am currently in, S is some library class, Item collects and organises data and data manipulation processes. Now I want to parallelise the work, for that I use the python multiprocessing module:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
l= [Item() for i in range(5)]
for i in l:
    Process(target=i.increase).start()
```

The result is not what I expected:

```
[i.c for i in l]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use of static methods, but rather with the way the multiprocessing module works. When you start a new `Process` it gets a *copy* of each object `i`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python?rq=1 for instance.  To obtain a mutated object back you must either send it back from the Process, or put it in a shared area: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: This seems to be the issue, if you do post it as an answer, I can give you the mark! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting your mutator, the static method `increase` in class `S` (called from the non-static `increase` in class `item`) to adjust each `i.c` field—and it does.  The problem is not with the static method, but rather with the internal design of `multiprocessing`.

The `multiprocessing` package works by running multiple separate instances of Python.  On Unix-like systems, it uses `fork`, which makes this easier; on Windows-like systems, it spawns new copies of itself.  Either way, this imposes all the slightly odd restrictions described in the Python documentation: [v2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) and [v3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).  (NB: the rest of the links below are to the Python2 documentation since that was the page I still had open.  The restrictions are pretty much the same for both Python2 and Python3.)

In this particular case, each `Process` call makes a copy of the object `i` and sends that copy to a new process.  The process modifies the copy, which has no effect on the original.

To fix this, you may either send the modified objects back, e.g., through a [Queue() or Pipe() instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), or place the objects into [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).  The send-back technique is simpler and easier to program and automatically does most of the necessary synchronization (but see the caveat about being sure to collect all results before using a Process instance's `join`, even implicitly).